# Accordion not working when it clicks on header

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

code work fine when it is single page but when i add in my angular app then code is not working,when user click on accordion header then it link to (#collapse id)
what is wrong with my code when i adding to my app.
        
    
    
    
    
    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js">

```
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Accordion Example</h2>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible     elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">login</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="panel-body">
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="password">
<input type="button" value="login">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap accordion will not work with angular. You need a directive to expand and collapse accordion.

Comment: Can you post your whole `<head>` so we can check if you've got the right JavaScript and CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bootstrap components like Accordion with AngularJS you'll need to use the specific bindings for them. They can be found (with some example code) at [this GitHub project](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

You'll need to swap the normal Bootstrap JavaScript file for the one above, and make sure you get the version with the templates included otherwise it won't work out of the box. The file with the templates included has `tpls` in the file name. There are plenty of examples of how to use this code, but feel free to ask if you have any more problems.